# page can not reload or access under HTML5 mode

Tags: angularjs

I want to enable my site can show NON-ASCII on the URL link,

One way is to enable html5Mode `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('#').html5Mode(true);`

However, after I turned on the html5Mode, I couldn't refresh the page when I'm at NON-root path.

How could I fix the problem, the problem seems cons over than pros.

```
app.config(function($locationProvider) {
   // return $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   // $locationProvider.hashPrefix('#').html5Mode(true);
 });
```

## Update

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  dev.co;
    root /Users/frontend/src;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html ;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

}
```

After adding these settings on nginx.conf

Still not working, when I tried to reload it again. I got this error [image: inline]

Comment: What language are you using for the backend?

Comment: Pure front-end project NO backend, the request is dispatched by NGINX directly not by any backend framework

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some server side rewrites, check this article: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions 
***UPDATE:*** 
For Nginx try this:

```
server {
    server_name my-app;

    root /path/to/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using pure front-end project NO any backend, the request is dispatched by NGINX directly not by any backend framework

Comment: There is a section of the article called Nginx Rewrites, try this:

server {
    server_name my-app;

    root /path/to/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}